# Combining Two Jquery Plug-ins: Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Okay, so I have been trying to combine the CarouFredSel and jquery custom content scroller to add an image of a scroll bar that works with the carousel. I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong since I am new to Jquery (very, very new).

Here is the script:

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.touchwipe.1.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.carouFredSel-5.5.0-packed.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function() {

        $("#foo3").carouFredSel({
            items   : 2,
            auto: {
                duration: 750
                },
            scroll  : {
                items: 1,
                duration: 750,
                mousewheel: true,
                wipe: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
            onAfter: function() {
  if ( $(this).triggerHandler( "currentPosition" ) == 0 ) {
    $(this).trigger( "pause" );
  }
}},
        }).parent().css("margin", "auto");
        });

    </script>
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="portfolio_gallery">
        <div class="list_carousel">

         <div id="mcs5_container">
<div class="customScrollBox">
<div class="horWrapper">
<div class="container">
<div class="content"> <p><ul id="foo3">
            <li style="width:486px"><img src="Images/SMP-3.jpg" alt="Testing description" /></li>
                <li style="width:486px"><img src="Images/SMP-6.jpg" alt="Text_2" /></li>
                <li style="width:238px"><img src="Images/SMP-4.jpg" alt="Text_6" /></li>
                <li style="width:486px"><img src="Images/SMP-2.jpg" alt="Text_3" /></li>
                  <li style="width:238px"><img src="Images/SMP-5.jpg" alt="new description" /></li>
                <li style="width:486px"><img src="Images/SMP-1.jpg" longdesc="" width="486" height="360" alt="Text_5" /></li>

          </ul>
            </p><div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="dragger_container">
<div class="dragger"></div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- scroll buttons -->
<a class="scrollUpBtn" href="#"></a> <a class="scrollDownBtn" href="#"></a>
</div>
</div>
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
     #mcs5_container .customScrollBox{overflow:auto;}
    #mcs5_container .dragger_container{display:none;}
</style>
</noscript>

</div>
<script>
$(window).load(function() {
      $("#mcs5_container").mCustomScrollbar("horizontal",500,"easeOutCirc",1,"fixed","yes","yes",20); 
});
</script>
<script src="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is a link to what I have accomplished thus far: http://2938.sandbox.i3dthemes.net/index-scroll-w-bar.html - you can see that everything works and looks the way I want, but the slider bar does not move?

HELP.... please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Change The first 6 lines above

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.touchwipe.1.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.carouFredSel-5.5.0-packed.js"></script>
```

To The following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.touchwipe.1.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.carouFredSel-5.5.0-packed.js"></script>
```

Do note the ordering of the Attached Script file;

```
jquery.js
jquery.easing.1.3.js
jquery-ui.min.js
jquery.mousewheel.js
jquery.touchwipe.1.1.1.js
jquery.carouFredSel-5.5.0-packed.js
```

Comment: thank you. Just so that I understand why this works, is it because the library comes first, then the ui, then the plugins?

Answer (score 2):

You should load jQuery Core first and then load Its UI library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not referencing your scripts in the expected order, thus jQuery UI does not get instanciated correctly and the mCustomScrollbar plugin does not work.

[image]

Very first one should be jQuery, then jQuery UI:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not sure why that was happening, but totally get it now.